# Cant move left or right while in a jump

Tags: c#, xna

Hey i am having a problem while my player is jumping where i cannot move left or right but i can move when he lands.  I need this in my jump so that i cant move from platform to platform etc...

Here is my code:

```
 public void handleInput(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            this.Transform.MoveIncrement = Vector2.Zero;
            float timeBetweenUpdates = 0.25f * gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;

            if (game.KeyboardManager.isKeyDown(left))
            {
                this.Transform.MoveIncrement += -this.Transform.Look * timeBetweenUpdates;
                this.Transform.IsMoved = true;
            }
            if (game.KeyboardManager.isKeyDown(right))
            {
                this.Transform.MoveIncrement += this.Transform.Look * timeBetweenUpdates;
                this.Transform.IsMoved = true;
            }
            if (game.KeyboardManager.isKeyDown(up) && hasJumped == false)
            {
                this.Transform.moveBy(-Vector2.UnitY * 400);
                this.Transform.IsMoved = true;
                hasJumped = true;
            }
            if (hasJumped == true)
            {
                this.Transform.MoveIncrement = Vector2.UnitY * timeBetweenUpdates;
                this.Transform.IsMoved = true;
                //hasJumped = false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're overwriting your previous assignment of `this.Transform.MoveIncrement` inside your `if (hasJumped == true)` block. This means that if a player is both moving and jumping, you assign their movement and then overwrite it with the jump movement. You should be somehow adding them together, not overwriting.

Comment: Solved i created a method moveBy and change moveIncrement to this.  I didnt know i could overwrite that value.  Thanks very much :).